# Getting stuck in Python while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

One of my python loops is working perfectly while the other one is completely broken:

```
omonth = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
while True:
    if int(omonth) not in (1,12):
        omonth = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
    else:
        break

oday = int(input('Digite o dia do seu nascimento: '))
while True:
    if int(oday) not in (1,31):
        day = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
    else:
        break
```

I'm trying to use a while loop to keep asking for an input when incorrect information is typed, and the first loop (omonth) is working perfectly, however the second loop (oday) repeats the input no matter what I type and never breaks.

Comment: Simple typo in your code. In the 2nd loop you set  day = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: ')) instead of oday. Change day to oday.

Comment: Simple typo as already identified by @FuadHasan but have you also noticed that you can only enter either 1 **or** 12 for the month and 1 **or** 31 for the day? Neither (1,12) nor (1,31) are ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello from a fellow brazilian!

That's happening because on this part of the code

```
while True:
if int(oday) not in (1,31):
    day = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
```

You're attributing a value to the variable `day` instead of `oday` inside your if conditional.

But besides that, your code has a bunch of flaws and will not work correctly.

First of all, this condition

```
if int(omonth) not in (1,12):
```

checks if `omonth` is equal to 1 or 12, not if it's in between them. The same logic applies to the `oday` loop.

Second, the `int` function in `int(omonth)` is redundant since you're already using `int(input())`

A better (and correct) implementation of your code would be:

```
omonth = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
while True:
    if not (1 <= omonth <= 12):
        omonth = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
    else:
        break

oday = int(input('Digite o dia do seu nascimento: '))
while True:
    if not (1 <= oday <= 31):
        oday = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: All months have more than 12 days

Comment: Oh, yeah, there's that. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2):

In the second loop, the line `day = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))` contains an error. The variable `day` is being assigned the value of the user's input, but it should be `oday` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous answers, you may also use a `while` loop to avoid doubling the input statement ([DRY rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). It would also prevent the typo you just made. ;-)
Additionally, it saves you the `else break` part.

This, however, requires initializing the destination variable with a value outside the desired range, so that the loop's body is executed at least once:

```
# initialize with an invalid value to make sure the condition is not satisfied
omonth = 0

while omonth not in range(1,12):
    omonth = int(input('Digite o mês do seu nascimento: '))
```